# Show by induction -Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Show by induction that for all $z\notin\{-1,1\}$ one has

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n z^{2 k} = \frac{1-z^{2n+2}}{1-z^2}\ .$$

Deduce that if $z<1$,

$$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^{2 k} = \frac{1}{1 - z^2}\ .$$

Comment: Please be more clear and also show what you've done so far.

Comment: Go to the FAQ section and follow there directions to write mathematics properly with LaTeX there.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I did it for OP.

Comment: Are you really saying that you didn't study the convergence of a geometric series rigorously in class/lecture notes/textbook? I'm fairly sure that your teacher has done that. Find it, and study the solution for ideas (i.e. copy more or less verbatim)!

Answer (score 2):

The equality is clear for $n=0$.

Suppose that the equality is true for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, now for $n+1$ we have
 $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} z^{2 k}=\sum_{k = 0}^{n}z^{2k}+z^{2(n+1)} = \frac{1-z^{2n+2}}{1-z^2}+z^{2n+2}=\frac{1-z^{2n+2}}{1-z^2}+z^{2n+2}=\frac{1-z^{2n+4}}{1-z^2},$$
so the equality is also true and the induction is achieved.

Now if $|z|<1$ then the sequence $(z^n)$ converges to $0$ so you find

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{2k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} z^{2 k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-z^{2n+2}}{1-z^2}=\frac{1}{1-z^2}.$$